# JAXB marshalling exception

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm trying to convert by obj "Response" into an XML using JAXB. But i don't want to add one of the data members(here "responseData") of my object to XML. But I'm getting an exception - 
"IlleagalAnnotationException".
Property responseData is present but not specified in @XmlType.propOrder 
This is my code..

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Root")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"payload", "result"})
public abstract class Response
{
    private String payload;
    private String result;

    @XmlElement(name = "Payload")
    public String getPayload() {
      return payload;
    }
    public void setPayload(String payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }
    @XmlElement(name = "Result")
    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }
    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public abstract String getResponseData() ;
    public abstract void setResponseData(String responseData) ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `@XmlTransient` to ignore it.

```
@XmlTransient
public abstract String getResponseData();
```